# get All Grandchildren according to attributes' binding recursively

Tags: jquery, dom, data-binding

```
<div data-id="123">123</div>
<div data-id="120" data-parent="123">120</div>
<div data-id="115" data-parent="123">115</div>


<div data-id="240">240</div>
<div data-id="245" data-parent="240">245</div>
<div data-id="246" data-parent="240">246</div>
<div data-id="247" data-parent="240">247</div>


<div data-id="255" data-parent="245">255</div>
<div data-id="256" data-parent="245">256</div>
```

We have above a tree presented by using two attributes :

1. `data-id`
2. `data-parent`

Thus, the terminology of child-parent is not got via `$().parent()` or  `$().children()`

However ,

```
$.fn.treeChildren=function(){
   return $('div[data-parent='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']');
}
```

Then :

```
$('[data-id=240]').treeChildren() // [245,246,247]
```

### Issue  :

> this plugin retrieves only the children , not children , children of >children , ... so on.

How to get all **Grandchildren** where the expected result of  `$('[data-id=240]').treeChildren()` is `[245,246,247,255,256]` not only `[245,246,247]`

Known that the following  algo didn't work :

```
$.fn.treeGrChildren=function(){
   if($('div[data-parent='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').treeChildren().length){
      return $('div[data-parent='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').treeGrChildren();
   }else{
      return $('div[data-parent='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']');
    }
}
```

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/xabgazk3/)

Comment: i have change in plugin may be this wll help you http://jsfiddle.net/xabgazk3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood the question correctly. Using

`$('...').find('div')`

will provide you with the flat list of all children and grandchildren. You can then extract the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your code retrieves only those divs with: `data-parent="240"`
Change these two line like this:

```
<div data-id="255" data-parent="240">255</div>
<div data-id="256" data-parent="240">256</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xabgazk3/1/

Or something like this:

```
$('#results').append( $('[data-id=240]').treeChildren().clone())
$('#results').append( $('[data-id=245]').treeChildren().clone())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xabgazk3/2/

There is no childrens or parents in your html code as of now. Children() traverse a single level down the DOM tree. To traverse down multiple levels (to return grandchildren or other descendants), use the find() method.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to persist this tree in Javascript object

```
function MyTreeNode(id,parent){
   this.data=id;
   this.parent=parent;
   this.parent.children.push(this);
    this.children=this.children || [];
}
```

Then , get all grand-children  by implementing a method for MyTreeNode .

i.e :

```
MyTreeNode.prototype.grandChildren=function(){
   // return children of this.children recursively 
}
```

So if i want all grandchildren of `div#240` just :

1. Call the following to get CSS  selectors of grandchildren

`var selectorsGrandCh=node240.grandChildren().map(function(child){return 'div[data-id='+child.data+']'}).join(',') ;`

2. Then use jquery : `$(selectorsGrandCh)`